# Mysql, update a column with multi records

Tags: mysql

I have four columns here: `date`, `value`, `ratio`, `id`. And I want to set ratio's value to today's value / yesterday's value with the same id, how can I do it within one mysql sentence? Further more, if the date is the earliest, set ratio to 1.

Comment: this is the basic query for updating multi records     UPDATE table-name 
       SET column-name = value, column-name = value, ...
     WHERE condition, now question is what have you tried to do....

Comment: I don't quite familiar with mysql so I add a colunm to store yesterday's value and then try update set, but I wonder if this can be done in one step

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
UPDATE table1 a
LEFT JOIN table1 b ON b.id = a.id AND b.`date` = DATE_SUB(a.`date`, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
SET ratio = IIF(b.`value` IS NULL, 1, a.`value` / b.`value`)
;
```

Note that this will replace ratio for the entire table...